# Exception in setting tags in buttons in Custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have set the tag in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as

`cell.noOfCommentsButton.tag=indexPath.row;` where `noOfCommentsButton` is my UIButton.

And i have defined IBAction for this button as:

```
- (IBAction)showComments:(BlogCell *)sender{
    int tag=[(UIButton *)sender.noOfCommentsButton tag];
    NSLog(@"The tag clicked:%d",tag);  
}
```

where Blogcell is my class for the custom cell.

But i am getting an exception on the line `NSLog(@"The tag clicked:%d",tag);` and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - (IBAction)showComments:(BlogCell *)sender{

This is wrong - the `sender` is the button, not the cell. So it should be:

```
- (IBAction)showComments:(UIButton *)sender {
```

Comment: 10 seconds faster than my own answer, so +1 to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the NSLog to this

```
NSLog(@"The tag clicked:%il",(long)tag);
```

If there's an error on the log that is.

Thanks, Jim